# How to use SQL to flatten a table with arrays in multiple columns?

Tags: sql, arrays, presto

How do I transform this table with arrays in num and letter columns:

```
 id  |    num    |  letter
-----+-----------+-----------
 111 | [1, 2]    | [a, b]
 111 | [3, 4]    | [c, d]
 222 | [5, 6, 7] | [e, f, g]
```

into this table

```
 id  | num | letter
-----+-----+--------
 111 |   1 | a
 111 |   2 | b
 111 |   3 | c
 111 |   4 | d
 222 |   5 | e
 222 |   6 | f
 222 |   7 | g
```

Appendix:
here is some sql to play around with to try to perform the transformation

```
with test as(
  select * from (
    values
        (111, array[1,2], array['a','b']),
        (111, array[3,4], array['c','d']),
        (222, array[5,6,7], array['e','f', 'g'])
  ) as t (id, num, letter)
)
select
 *
from test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PrestoDB seems to support [`unnest()`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html) with multiple arguments:

```
select t.id, u.n, u.l
from test cross join
     unnest(num, letter) as u(n, l)
```

Comment: Thanks works great!  I was a separate cross join for each column, but of course that doesn't work!

Comment: @RexSalisbury you can zip the arrays together before unnesting: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#zip

Comment: @DainSundstrom curious if you have an example of what that would look like.  Also is there any advantage?